# Как отлаживать приложения nw.js?

Tags: node.js, отладка

Когда использую `gui.Window.get().showDevTools();` открывается пустое окно.
Если использую `--remote-debugging-port=9222`, то страница `http://localhost:9222/` в браузере не открывается. Что я делаю не так? [image: nw --remote-debugging-port=9222]